# Atomikos 5 connection pool monitoring using JMX

Tags: spring-boot, monitoring, jmx, atomikos

My application uses Atomikos 5.0.6 with Spring, how can I monitor my connection pool settings in JMX? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can do this. For example, you can expose your own JMX Mbeans to Spring with safe attributes:

```java
public class AtomikosDataSourceBeanMBean extends AtomikosDataSourceBean {
    public AtomikosDataSourceBeanMBean() { super(); }

    public int getPoolAvailableSize() { return super.poolAvailableSize(); }
    public int getPoolTotalSize()     { return super.poolTotalSize(); }

    // ...
}
```

However, (commercial) Atomikos provides JMX support out of the box using a library named `transactions-jmx`, which provides monitoring for:

- UniqueResourceName
- MinPoolSize
- MaxPoolSize
- AvailableConnectionsInPool
- CurrentPoolSize
- BusyConnectionsInPool
- PercentageOfPoolCapacityUsed
- LastPoolExhaustionHappenedAt
- LastReapHappenedAt

In which you can inject your own beans to monitor:

```java
@Bean
public JmxAtomikosDataSourceBeanMBean jmxAtomikosDataSourceBeanMBean(DataSource xaDataSource) {
    JmxAtomikosDataSourceBean bean = new JmxAtomikosDataSourceBean();
    bean.setMonitoredBean((AtomikosDataSourceBean) xaDataSource);
    return bean;
}

@Bean
public JmxAtomikosConnectionFactoryBeanMBean jmxAtomikosConnectionFactoryBeanMBean() {
    JmxAtomikosConnectionFactoryBean bean = new JmxAtomikosConnectionFactoryBean();
    bean.setMonitoredBean((AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean) jmsConnectionFactory());
    return bean;
}
```

Which you can then export as MBeans:

```xml
<bean id="exporter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter" lazy-init="false">
    <property name="beans">
        <map>
        <entry key="something:type=statistics,application=myApp,name=atomikosDataSource"
               value-ref="jmxAtomikosDataSourceBeanMBean"/>
        <entry key="something:type=statistics,application=myApp,name=atomikosConnectionFactory"
               value-ref="jmxAtomikosConnectionFactoryBeanMBean"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Hope it helps.